# Can't represent a size of 357913941 in Constraints in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, grid, android-jetpack-compose, height

I have a CustomGrid that is inside a Column. That column is inside a HorizontalPager and the HorizontalPager is inside another column where there are other elements. I want the Grid to grow in height as much as necessary, but whenever I add fillMaxHeight() or wrapContentSize() or another equivalent method, the application crashes with the error you can see in the title. Is there anything I can do to fix this error and have the Grid take up as much space as I need?
I leave you the prints of my Grid, which is custom, and the respective components.

Custom Grid code:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.Stable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.Layout
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.Measurable
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ParentDataModifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Constraints
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Density
import kotlin.math.max

interface GridScope {
    @Stable
    fun Modifier.span(columns: Int = 1, rows: Int = 1) = this.then(
        GridData(columns, rows)
    )

    companion object : GridScope
}

private class GridData(
    val columnSpan: Int,
    val rowSpan: Int,
) : ParentDataModifier {

    override fun Density.modifyParentData(parentData: Any?): Any = this@GridData

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as GridData

        if (columnSpan != other.columnSpan) return false
        if (rowSpan != other.rowSpan) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = columnSpan
        result = 31 * result + rowSpan
        return result
    }
}

private val Measurable.gridData: GridData?
    get() = parentData as? GridData

private val Measurable.columnSpan: Int
    get() = gridData?.columnSpan ?: 1

private val Measurable.rowSpan: Int
    get() = gridData?.rowSpan ?: 1

data class GridInfo(
    val numChildren: Int,
    val columnSpan: Int,
    val rowSpan: Int,
)

@Composable
fun Grid(
    columns: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable GridScope.() -> Unit,
) {
    check(columns > 0) { "Columns must be greater than 0" }
    Layout(
        content = { GridScope.content() },
        modifier = modifier,
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        // calculate how many rows we need
        val standardGrid = GridData(1, 1)
        val spans = measurables.map { measurable -> measurable.gridData ?: standardGrid }
        val gridInfo = calculateGridInfo(spans, columns)
        val rows = gridInfo.sumOf { it.rowSpan }

        // build constraints
        val baseConstraints = Constraints.fixed(
            width = constraints.maxWidth / columns,
            height = constraints.maxHeight / rows,
        )
        val cellConstraints = measurables.map { measurable ->
            val columnSpan = measurable.columnSpan
            val rowSpan = measurable.rowSpan
            Constraints.fixed(
                width = baseConstraints.maxWidth * columnSpan,
                height = baseConstraints.maxHeight * rowSpan
            )
        }

        // measure children
        val placeables = measurables.mapIndexed { index, measurable ->
            measurable.measure(cellConstraints[index])
        }

        // place children
        layout(
            width = constraints.maxWidth,
            height = constraints.maxHeight,
        ) {
            var x = 0
            var y = 0
            var childIndex = 0
            gridInfo.forEach { info ->
                repeat(info.numChildren) {
                    val placeable = placeables[childIndex++]
                    placeable.placeRelative(
                        x = x,
                        y = y,
                    )
                    x += placeable.width
                }
                x = 0
                y += info.rowSpan * baseConstraints.maxHeight
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun calculateGridInfo(
    spans: List<GridData>,
    columns: Int,
): List<GridInfo> {
    var currentColumnSpan = 0
    var currentRowSpan = 0
    var numChildren = 0
    return buildList {
        spans.forEach { span ->
            val columnSpan = span.columnSpan.coerceAtMost(columns)
            val rowSpan = span.rowSpan
            if (currentColumnSpan + columnSpan <= columns) {
                currentColumnSpan += columnSpan
                currentRowSpan = max(currentRowSpan, rowSpan)
                ++numChildren
            } else {
                add(
                    GridInfo(
                        numChildren = numChildren,
                        columnSpan = currentColumnSpan,
                        rowSpan = currentRowSpan
                    )
                )
                currentColumnSpan = columnSpan
                currentRowSpan = rowSpan
                numChildren = 1
            }
        }
        add(
            GridInfo(
                numChildren = numChildren,
                columnSpan = currentColumnSpan,
                rowSpan = currentRowSpan,
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Code where Grid will be inserted or other components, it is generated based on data that comes from API:

```
Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(backgroundColor.value)
    ) {

        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {

            // We only consume nested flings in the main-axis, allowing cross-axis flings to propagate
            // as normal
            val consumeFlingNestedScrollConnection =
                remember { ConsumeFlingNestedScrollConnection(consumeHorizontal = true) }

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(
                        backgroundColor.value,
                        RoundedCornerShape(topStart = Dimen30, topEnd = Dimen30)
                    )
                    .nestedScroll(connection = consumeFlingNestedScrollConnection)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                HorizontalPager(
                    count = size,
                    state = pagerState,
                    itemSpacing = Dimen20,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = Dimen33),
                    userScrollEnabled = false
                ) { page ->
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            // We don't any nested flings to continue in the pager, so we add a
                            // connection which consumes them.
                            .nestedScroll(connection = consumeFlingNestedScrollConnection)
                            // Constraint the content width to be <= than the width of the pager.
                            .fillParentMaxWidth()
                            .wrapContentSize()
                    ) {
                        // content (where grid could be, content is generated dinamically based on data that comes from api
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How Grid is added to that layout:

```
Grid(
                columns = 5,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = Dimen20, end = Dimen20, top = Dimen16)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentSize()
            ) {
// cards content
}
```

The crash points to the baseConstraints of the Grid code, but I can't figure out why and I can't solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `Constraints.fixed()` you need to have `Constraints` maxWidth and maxHeight that are not infinite.

When you apply Modifier.verticalScroll you transform your maxHeight to `Constraints.Infinity` which is `2147483647`. I explained in detail [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73250986/different-types-of-width-in-jetpack-compose/73258726#73258726) about constraints with vertical scroll and `Constraints`.

[image]

And created a sample to show why it crashes

```
@Composable
private fun Grid(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {

    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content
    ) { measurables, constraints ->

        val placeables = measurables.map { measurable: Measurable ->
            measurable.measure(
                Constraints.fixed(
                    width = constraints.maxWidth,
                    height = constraints.maxHeight
                )
            )
        }
        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
            placeables.forEach {
                it.placeRelative(0, 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

demonstration why it crashes

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
) {
    HorizontalPager(count = 3) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
        ) {
            Grid() {
                BoxWithConstraints() {
                    Text("Constraints: ${this.constraints}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What you should be doing is to constrain maxHeight to parent or screen size.

One, and simple way to do is, passing it via Modifier.onSizeChanged to your `Layout`, but be careful using `Modifier.onSizeChanged` which you might trigger recomposition continuously when mutableState is used to update or set size of another Composable.

```
var height by remember {
    mutableStateOf(0)
}
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .onSizeChanged {
            if (height == 0) {
                height = it.height
            }
        }
){
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        HorizontalPager(count = 3) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
            ) {
                Grid(height = height) {
                    BoxWithConstraints {
                        Text("Constraints: ${this.constraints}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use parent height instead of infinite height due to Modifier.verticalScroll

```
@Composable
private fun Grid(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    height:Int,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {

    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content
    ) { measurables, constraints ->

        val placeables = measurables.map { measurable: Measurable ->
            measurable.measure(
                Constraints.fixed(
                    width = constraints.maxWidth,
                    height = constraints.maxHeight.coerceAtMost(height)
                )
            )
        }
        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
            placeables.forEach {
                it.placeRelative(0, 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Changing your Compsable based on sample above you can achieve what you wish to create

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to understand why it happens, but with the way you suggested, my items on the grid don't appear. I need to have an item per line that occupies 60% of the width and another 40%. How can I do that with your logic?

Comment: It's not easy to test from the code you shared but you can either debug or print logs what `cellConstraints`contain as min/max width and height, placable dimensions are and check out `layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.MaxHeight)`. one or multiple of these probably needs to be updated

Comment: If placeable dimension are correct,  60% of the width and another 40% and heights of your grid items are finite then you might need to update layout height or width

Comment: Cell constraint are not used with your logic. On Grid method, I just replaced my placeable with your placeables, it crashes on baseContraints, probably because the calculations will still be made.

Comment: This is not a method. You need to limit fixed constraints finite for `Constraints.fixed`. You can update your dimension measurement using finite constraints. `Cell constraint are not used with your logic`. What i posted is an example how to keep your constraints in parent dimensions. You need to debug what are your `baseConstraints`, and `cellConstraints` are. Start with debug and go step by step to check out what constraints and placeables are

Comment: I was able to put it working as I pretend. Thank you so much for your help.