# How to use IntrinsicSize.Min with canvas in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I am following the document of [Intrinsics](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements#intrinsics-in-action). I want to wrap the canvas view.  I want to use canvas into multiple times because I want to make timeline view. So drawing in the canvas is everything works fine.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTextApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun CanvasView() {
    val titleTextMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    val titleText = "Hello world!!"
    val listOfPair = listOf(
        Pair("Text 1", "app"),
        Pair("Text 2", "link"),
        Pair("Text 3", "app"),
        Pair("Text 4", "link"),
        Pair("Text 5", ""),
    )
    val multipleString = buildAnnotatedString {
        listOfPair.forEachIndexed { _, item ->
            val (text, type) = item
            when (type) {
                "app" -> {
                    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.DarkGray)) {
                        append("$text\n")
                    }
                }

                "link" -> {
                    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.Blue)) {
                        append("$text\n")
                    }
                }

                else -> {
                    append("$text\n")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    val titleTextLayoutResult = remember {
        titleTextMeasurer.measure(titleText, TextStyle(fontSize = 16.sp))
    }
    val multipleTextLayoutResult = remember {
        titleTextMeasurer.measure(multipleString, TextStyle(fontSize = 14.sp, lineHeight = 1.3.em))
    }
    val endPadding = with(LocalDensity.current) { 10.dp.toPx() }
    val circleSize = with(LocalDensity.current) { 6.dp.toPx() }
    CanvasContent(
        titleTextLayoutResult,
        multipleTextLayoutResult,
        circleSize,
        endPadding,
    )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalTextApi::class)
@Composable
fun CanvasContent(
    titleTextLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult,
    multipleTextLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult,
    circleSize: Float,
    endPadding: Float,
) {
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val circleX = (center.x / 2) + (titleTextLayoutResult.size.width / 2) - endPadding
        drawText(
            textLayoutResult = titleTextLayoutResult,
            topLeft = Offset(
                x = center.x - titleTextLayoutResult.size.width / 2,
                y = center.y - titleTextLayoutResult.size.height / 2,
            )
        )
        drawText(
            textLayoutResult = multipleTextLayoutResult,
            topLeft = Offset(
                x = center.x - titleTextLayoutResult.size.width / 2,
                y = center.y + titleTextLayoutResult.size.height / 2,
            )
        )
        drawLine(
            color = Color.Black,
            start = Offset(x = circleX, y = 0F),
            end = Offset(x = circleX, y = center.y - circleSize),
            strokeWidth = 2.dp.toPx(),
        )
        drawLine(
            color = Color.Black,
            start = Offset(x = circleX, y = center.y + circleSize),
            end = Offset(x = circleX, y = size.height),
            strokeWidth = 2.dp.toPx(),
        )
        drawCircle(
            color = Color.Gray,
            radius = circleSize,
            center = Offset(circleX, center.y)
        )
    }
}
```

The view looks full screen like this

[image]

Now I want to use this view in multiple times. I tried the parent item to `height(IntrinsicSize.Min)` and inside `Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())` it not warping the view i.e. view is not visible any more. Code looks like this

```
Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
    ) {
        CanvasContent(
            titleTextLayoutResult,
            multipleTextLayoutResult,
            circleSize,
            endPadding,
        )
    }
```

So view is not visible any more. So what is the wrong in here?

My main goal is to create the view like below image.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this inside a loop for each draw element by increasing height with an index

```
// This is for demonstration
val offset = 50.dp.toPx()

for(i in 0..2) {


  drawText(
            textLayoutResult = titleTextLayoutResult,
            topLeft = Offset(
                x = center.x - titleTextLayoutResult.size.width / 2,
                y = center.y - titleTextLayoutResult.size.height / 2 + i * offset,
            )
        )
}
   // Rest of the drawing on each iteration
}
```

You can't use `IntrinsicSize.Min` with `Canvas`, you can't even use a non-fixed(`Modifier.heighIn(min,max)`) size if you wish to get a non-zero `size` from `DrawScope` because Canvas is a Spacer with `Modifier.drawBehind{}`. And as you can see in source code below it returns 0 width or height if you don't assign a fixed size modifier.

You can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73258726/5457853) which modifier returns which kind of `Constraints` with different kind of flags

```
@Composable
fun Canvas(modifier: Modifier, onDraw: DrawScope.() -> Unit) =
    Spacer(modifier.drawBehind(onDraw))

@Composable
@NonRestartableComposable
fun Spacer(modifier: Modifier) {
    Layout({}, measurePolicy = SpacerMeasurePolicy, modifier = modifier)
}

private object SpacerMeasurePolicy : MeasurePolicy {

    override fun MeasureScope.measure(
        measurables: List<Measurable>,
        constraints: Constraints
    ): MeasureResult {
        return with(constraints) {
            val width = if (hasFixedWidth) maxWidth else 0
            val height = if (hasFixedHeight) maxHeight else 0
            layout(width, height) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Even if you assign `Modifier.draw` to a `Box` or `Column` you won't be able to use intrinsic size because, intrinsic size is some kind of placeholder assigned to Composables in `MeasurePolicy`. So there has to be some Composables like `Text` or `Image` as child Composable to get intrinsic size from.

Let's say you have 3 `Text`s. To get max height of these `Text`s parent needs to get biggest of this intrinsic heights and then measure itself with max of the `Text`s.

For example this Layout assigns fixed numbers for demonstration

```
@Composable
fun CustomColumnWithIntrinsicDimensions(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val measurePolicy = object : MeasurePolicy {

        override fun MeasureScope.measure(
            measurables: List<Measurable>,
            constraints: Constraints
        ): MeasureResult {

            val looseConstraints = constraints.copy(minHeight = 0)
            val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
                measurable.measure(looseConstraints)
            }

            var yPosition = 0

            val totalHeight: Int = placeables.sumOf {
                it.height
            }

            //  This can be sum or longest of Composable widths, or maxWidth of Constraints
            val maxWidth: Int = placeables.maxOf {
                it.width
            }

            return layout(maxWidth, totalHeight) {
                placeables.forEach { placeable ->
                    placeable.placeRelative(x = 0, y = yPosition)
                    yPosition += placeable.height
                }
            }
        }

        override fun IntrinsicMeasureScope.minIntrinsicHeight(
            measurables: List<IntrinsicMeasurable>,
            width: Int
        ): Int {

            println(" minIntrinsicHeight() width: $width, measurables: ${measurables.size}")
            //  This is just sample to show usage of minIntrinsicHeight, don't set
            // static values
            return 200
        }

        override fun IntrinsicMeasureScope.maxIntrinsicHeight(
            measurables: List<IntrinsicMeasurable>,
            width: Int
        ): Int {

            println(" maxIntrinsicHeight() width: $width, measurables: ${measurables.size}")

            //  This is just sample to show usage of maxIntrinsicHeight, don't set
            // static values
            return 400
        }
    }

    Layout(modifier = modifier, content = content, measurePolicy = measurePolicy)
}
```

You can see how size is set when you assign intrinsic sizes in demo below

[image]

```
Text(text = "No height Modifier")
CustomColumnWithIntrinsicDimensions(
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(100.dp)
        .background(Green400)
        .padding(4.dp)
) {
    Text(
        "First Text",
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color(0xffF44336)),
        color = Color.White
    )
    Text(
        "Second Text",
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color(0xff9C27B0)),
        color = Color.White
    )
}

Text(text = "height(IntrinsicSize.Min)")
CustomColumnWithIntrinsicDimensions(
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(100.dp)
        .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
        .background(Yellow400)
        .padding(4.dp)
) {
    Text(
        "First Text",
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color(0xffF44336)),
        color = Color.White
    )
    Text(
        "Second Text",
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color(0xff9C27B0)),
        color = Color.White
    )
}

Text(text = "height(IntrinsicSize.Max)")
CustomColumnWithIntrinsicDimensions(
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(100.dp)
        .height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
        .background(Blue400)
        .padding(4.dp)
) {
    Text(
        "First Text",
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color(0xffF44336)),
        color = Color.White
    )
    Text(
        "Second Text",
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color(0xff9C27B0)),
        color = Color.White
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks for explaining all in details. I still in confused what should be best solution to achieve my output.

Comment: Use for loop and increase y position via index yOffset = someHeight * index

Comment: My Canvas is taking full height so I want to wrap the height. I don't get it to be honest. Thanks

Comment: I don't my view heights, that's my main problem..

Comment: If you look on `listOfPair` variable that is coming from the web server and I don't know how many items coming. So that's the problem to know accurate height for the view...

Comment: That's what i explained, You can't use intrinsic size if it's not provided by child Composables. And to check what DrawScope size is you can observe `size` param. even if it's zero you can still draw any shape unless you use clip

Comment: You can get item size and set height for canvas if that's the case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253425/discussion-between-thracian-and-vivek-modi).

Comment: I am accepting this answer because you teach me that Canvas will need height. We cannot use `IntrinsicSize.Min` in this situation. Thanks