# How to left-align oversize composables in a Column

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

If I have items that are wider than the containing `Column`, how can I achieve that all items are left aligned and clipped only at their right side?
Here is an example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun RandomTriangle(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val width = rand.nextInt(20, 500).dp
    Box(modifier
        .height(30.dp)
        .requiredWidth(width)
        .drawBehind {
            val path = Path().apply {
                moveTo(0f, 0f)
                lineTo(size.width, size.height / 2)
                lineTo(0f, size.height)
                close()
            }
            drawPath(path, Brush.horizontalGradient(listOf(Color.Green, Color.Blue)))
        })
}

@Preview(widthDp = 100)
@Composable
fun ListTestPreview() {
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        List(5) { RandomTriangle(Modifier.padding(4.dp)) }
    }
}
```

This yields the following result:

[image: Preview]

As you can see, the second, fourth and fifth triangles (from top to bottom) are oversize. They are centered in the parent `Column` and clipped left and right, but I would like them to be left-aligned and clipped on the right side only.

I already tried `clipToBounds()` on the `Column`, and `.align(Alignment.Start)` on the contained item; both do not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is about how layouts work in Jetpack Compose when you force   Constraints that are bigger than parent your Composable is placed at its (parentWidth-childWidth)/2. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73258726/5457853) for more details. `Modifier.requiredWidth/Height()` section explains this issue.

For instance

```
Column(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(20.dp)) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Green)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .requiredWidth(140.dp)
                .height(20.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
        )
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

Child with Red background with 140.dp width is placed at -20.dp inside parent. What you with that size is exactly this as you can bright green section of triangles are also not visible.

You should set start point as top of triangle with

```
moveTo(size.width, size.height / 2)
```

then draw line to bottom right of triangle with width either at 0 or less than 0 if you create a random with that is greater than Canvas width

Result

[image]

You can clip Composable to remove drawing outside Canvas only to draw what's inside canvas bounds.

```
@Composable
fun RandomTriangle(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val width = Random.nextInt(50, 220).dp

    Box(
        modifier
            .padding(start = 100.dp, top = 100.dp)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
            .height(30.dp)
            .width(200.dp)
            .drawWithCache {

                val widthPx = width.toPx()

                val path = Path().apply {
                    if (widthPx > size.width) {
                        moveTo(size.width, size.height / 2)
                        lineTo(size.width - widthPx, size.height.coerceAtMost(widthPx))
                        lineTo(size.width - widthPx, 0f)
                    } else {
                        moveTo(0f, 0f)
                        lineTo(widthPx, size.height / 2)
                        lineTo(0f, size.height)
                    }

                    close()
                }
                onDrawBehind {
                    drawPath(path, Brush.horizontalGradient(listOf(Color.Green, Color.Blue)))

                }
            }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Thracian's answer - the simpliest way to 'extend' bounds in one direction is to use `graphicsLayer` modifier with `scale`.

```
@Composable
fun RandomTriangle(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {        
    val scale = (10..300).random().toFloat()/100f // or whatever         
    Canvas(modifier = modifier
        .height(30.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .graphicsLayer(scaleX = scale,
            transformOrigin = TransformOrigin(pivotFractionX = 0f,
                pivotFractionY = 0f)))
    {
        val path = Path().apply {
            moveTo(0f, 0f)
            lineTo(size.width, size.height / 2)
            lineTo(0f, size.height)
            close()
        }
        drawPath(path, Brush.horizontalGradient(listOf(Color.Green, Color.Blue)))
    }
}
```

[image]